# Matlab copy matrix element to a vector

Tags: matlab

Let us say that I have a matrix B with dimension 44x4x451. I want to copy the element of B(1,1,:) to a vector. Do you know how to do it in Matlab?
I tried x(:) = B(1,1,:) but the dimension of x becomes 1x1x451. I want it to become 1x451.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = squeeze(B(1,1,:))
```